# Testing framework for HTML and CSS

Tags: html, node.js, css

My company has a customised version of Bootstrap to suit their guidelines. I'm looking to incorporate a testing tool to ensure the framework matches the guidelines, for example a h1 should be 48px when the screen size is 1200px etc.

I'm really struggling finding such a testing tool. I'm using node btw.

Has anyone got any recommendations?

Comment: The pros use Selenium

Answer (score 1):

There are several frameworks for testing front end, some of them are nightwatch.js , phantomCss , phantomJs, jasmine.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Laravel's Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/dusk) which is a wrapper for Selenium to provide browser tests.

- free
- great documentation
- great api
- if you disable headless, you see the browser testing your website, how cool!
- ability to test for multiple browsers, chrome by default